# Oracle JDBC Auto-Commit

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Lets say I have code that roughly resembles something like this: (Using oracle 10G jdbc). Will the transaction be committed in this specific scenario?

```
    public void someMethod(){
    try {
    OracleConnection connection = getConnectionFromPool();
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    // Do some transaction here - complete transaction, no errors occurred

    ...

    //Throw my own exception here
    throw new Exception("Custom Exception");


    } catch (Exception e}
    {
      ...
    }
    finally {
      connection.setAutoCommit(true);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Nope, you have to commit() the transaction if there are no errors, else roll back.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: @Sudhanshu: not according to the JDBC JavaDocs (see my answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to the JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29), it *should* commit:

> *NOTE: If this method is called during a transaction and the auto-commit mode is changed, the transaction is committed. If setAutoCommit is called and the auto-commit mode is not changed, the call is a no-op.*

**BUT**: if you rely on this, it means you rely on the driver to comply with this requirement - which is something I wouldn't do (I would never rely on something happing implicitely)

If you want to make sure your transaction is committed, call `commit()`.

Answer (score 0):

No. Either remove `connection.setAutoCommit(false);` or

```
finally {
      connection.commit();
    }
```

Comment: That's not what the documentation says.